# Google maps ob blackberry OS6

Tags: blackberry, maps

I was able to link to google map site to get nice full-screen google map using OS5.  On new Blackberry 6, OS seem to be shrinking all images.  As a result google map occupies less than 50% of screen.  Any work-around suggested. (Can't use applet for now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its a `Bitmap` then you could use `scaleInto()`

Comment: is scaleInto() a java function?  I am using html!